# Unable to remove files recursively from Git

Tags: git, rm

I want to remove all files from Git at ~/bin/.

I run

```
git rm -r --cached ~/.vim/*                      # Thanks to Pate in finding --cached!
```

I get

```
fatal: pathspec '.vim/colors' did not match any files
```

This error messsage suggests me to use the following PATHs, since ~/.vim/** does not work

```
~/.vim/*        # I get the error
~/.vim/*/*/*    # This removes files from the index at ~/.vim/folderA/folderB/file1.txt
~/.vim/*/*      # similar error as to the first PATH
```

**How can you remove all files and subdirectories at ~/.vim from Git?**

--

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
 git rm -r --cached ~/.vim/*   
 fatal: pathspec '.vim/colors' did not match any files
```

1/ You do not need the '`*`':

```
 git rm -r --cached ~/.vim
```

will take care of any tracked sub-files.

2/ `fatal: pathspec '.vim/colors' did not match any files` simply means one of your commands you tried before the one listed in 1/ has worked, and there is no more file to delete!

```
# to test that command, first reinitialize the state of the repository
# save first if you have any other current modifications
$ git reset --hard

# then check the rm works
$ git rm -r --cached ~/.vim
rm '.vim/aPath/aFile1'
rm '.vim/aSecondPath/aFile2'
rm '.vim/aThirdPath/aFile3'

# try it again
$ git rm -r --cached ~/.vim
fatal: pathspec '.vim/colors
```

Comment: Does this also remove from git any historical trace of those files from earlier versions?

Comment: @CraigHicks No it does not. For that, you would need git filter-branch (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) or BFG: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Answer (score 10):

You want to remove them even if there are local modifications?

```
git rm -rf bin/*
```

Or do you want to remove from the index but keep the files themselves?

```
git rm -r --cached bin/*
```

Also try out:

```
git help rm
```

Comment: @Pate: I want to remove the files from Git such that I have the files in my machine after the removal.

Comment: This answer is the foundation of the changed question.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand what `*` does a bit first.

Applications don't see `*` (or other globbing characters) -- they receive all of the matches of the glob as individual arguments.

To understand this better, put `echo` in front of your first command and see what it prints out:

```
 git rm -r --cached ~/.vim/*
```

You'll see each individual match, including things that the program doesn't know how to operate on (which includes `.vim/colors`).

Comment: I feel that this answer should have included the described echo, as well as a solution to the actual problem the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

Or it could be that the directory you're trying to recursively remove is in the .gitignore list. I just encountered this. I have ./vendors in my ignore list, and there are a bunch of directories under ./vendors but because anything in vendors is ignored, it's not actually deleting anything like ./vendors/assetic  because it's not actually in the repo. I forgot that it was in the ignore list :)