# How do I commit all deleted files in Git?

Tags: git, git-add

If I delete some files from the disk they come up as deleted like so in the Git repo:

```
C:\git\bc>git status
# On branch tracking2
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    test.txt
#
```

Is there a way to do a single command "just delete these files from the repository"?
Similar to `git add .` which would add all new and modified files to the stage.

I use Visual Studio and Windows explorer to work with my source tree and at some point I just delete a whole bunch of files. I then find it a pain to call `git rm` as the files are no longer around and there is no command line intellisense to help me type it in.

I just want a command that deletes all files from git that are also deleted from the disk.