# Git does not detect a deleted file

Tags: git, github, repository

I am trying to migrate my app code from bitbucket to github. I changed the remotes on my folder but when I tried to push on my new repo I had an error as I add a file that was too big in size. 
I deleted the file then `git add .` and commited the change but when I try to push the code on my repository, I still have the same error as if the big file is still there :

```
Counting objects: 7302, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5689/5689), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7302/7302), 385.41 MiB | 2.14 MiB/s, done.
Total 7302 (delta 3982), reused 3468 (delta 1527)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 22d95f5ef2a2bcab974f9ccbe5819675
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File wefootapp.zip is 351.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To git@github.com:davidgeismar/wefootapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:davidgeismar/wefootapp.git'
```

what should I do for git to understand that the file was deleted?

Comment: Did you delete the file with "git rm"?

Comment: @DenisFrezzato can you explain what is this file ?

Comment: "git rm /path/to/file" is a git command that removes files from the working tree and from the index. Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

Comment: thanks denis as I said below  
I tried that but I get ```➜ wefootapp git:(master) git rm /Users/davidgeismar/wefootapp/wefootapp.zip fatal: pathspec '/Users/davidgeismar/wefootapp/wefootapp.zip' did not match any files```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell git it's no longer there if you were tracking it.

`git rm ./local/path/to/file` will mark it deleted.

Edit: see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004453/how-to-remove-multiple-deleted-files-in-git-repository) regarding already-removed files answered.

Comment: I tried that but I get 
```➜  wefootapp git:(master) git rm /Users/davidgeismar/wefootapp/wefootapp.zip
fatal: pathspec '/Users/davidgeismar/wefootapp/wefootapp.zip' did not match any files```

Answer (score 0):

If you added a new commit with the file deleted after the one that introduced it, and there are no other changes you wish to keep after commiting the large file, you should `git reset --hard` to the commit that added the file, delete the file and then modify that commit with `git commit --amend`. You should probably add the file or an appropriate pattern to your `.gitignore` as well before that commit.

If you introcuded other changes you wish to keep after the big file, you can use `git filter-branch` to remove just that file from history. There's a good example fitting your case [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch).

As long as the file remains in a commit in your local history, your push will be rejected, so you must in one way or another rewrite your local history first.

Answer (score 0):

You should not place such a big file in git.
You should use this tool to clean your repository history:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

It the prefect tool for this kind of task

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

[image]

---

After you have cleaned your repository use [this tool](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store your large files.

[image]