# Howto "git ls" files marked by git as "deleted by us"

Tags: git, shell

I started to use git cherrypick; and as a result of that I am now (very often) facing situations that give me a lot of files marked as "deleted by us".

I saw [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004453/how-to-remove-multiple-deleted-files-in-git-repository), that mentioned how can use `git ls-files --deleted` to get a flat file list; which can then be piped to xargs rm.

Problem is: --deleted doesn't list those "deleted by us" files.

So, long story short: what is the easiest/straight forward way of removing the "deleted by us" files?

( I really liked the git ls-files approach; as that doesn't require sed/awk magic; so there is also no worrying about getting quotes right ...)

Update; just to explain why this not some "XY problem" situation:

- actually I am using git svn; to connect to some backend SVN server
- SVN trunk contains directories A, B, C
- I am making changes on **trunk** that affect all three directories
- But: the git where I run the cherry-pick ... actually resembles "product branches" created on the SVN server. These "product" branches do only contain subsets (so one has A and B; the other has B and C).
- I tried hard; but I really couldn't get to create a git svn clone that contains SVN trunk AND SVN product branches at the same time

Comment: what "deleted by us" actually mean?

Comment: `git ls-files --deleted | xargs rm` is **not** safe for filenames that need quoting. Just for the record. You need `git ls-files -z --deleted | xargs -0 rm` for that.

Comment: The real question is why are you often deleting files on your branch that others are changing on their branches?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a "simple" command like that for this but you can use `git status` itself for this.

```
while read -d '' status file; do
    case "$status" in
        (D?)
            echo "Removing $file that was deleted by us."
            #rm "./$file"
            ;;
    esac
    #printf 'status: %q\nfilename: %q\n' "$status" "$file"
done < <(git status -sz)
```

To match only `DU` and not `D?` (D single-character) change the case pattern appropriately.

To run `rm` only once use `files+=("$file")` in the `if` block and then `rm "${files[@]}"` at the end.

Comment: Doesn't work. When I run the command, I get output like:
`filename: /some/real/file \n File  was deleted by us.\n status: DU` (\n inserted by mself to indicate the line break).

Comment: What about that didn't work? (Assuming you reported the output out of order.) This snippet should just output each file with a difference and *also* output `File ... was deleted by us.` for each file that was deleted by us.

Comment: The point is: it prints "File  was deleted by us". The $filename seems to be empty. And, i found a nice solution in the meantime; that is good enough for the filesets we are using `git status --porcelain | grep "DU " | cut -d " " -f2 | xargs git rm` ( based on the fact that git status actually delivers different output (D vs DU) when called with that option)

Comment: Oh, that's because I typo'd the variable name. Use `$file` in the message instead and it'll work.

Comment: `-z` is `--porcelain -z` and yes, you can use `grep` and `cut` and `xargs` to do this or you could use a shell loop and either call `rm` N times or collect the filenames in an array and call `rm` once at the end.

Comment: So, if you update your answer, I am still inclined to accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To list unmerged files marked as "deleted by us" the following command can be used:

```sh
git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no | sed --silent 's/^DU //p'
```

or a slightly shorter variant:

```sh
git status --porcelain -uno | sed -n 's/^DU //p'
```

In the output of the command `git status --porcelain` the unmerged "deleted by us" files are marked with `DU`.

In `sed`, the option `-n` suppresses printing unless explicit requested, the command `s/X/Y/` substitute X (a regexp) by Y, and due to the flag `p` the modified line is printed.