# How to delete all files from repo that doesn't exist on my computer?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm new to Git (GitHub for me) and I hope that you could help me.

I work on one project and I often change names of files. Situation is that on my computer I have all files as I want, but in GitHub - all files: those I need and those I deleted (renamed files).

is there any way to automatically delete files that doesn't exist on my machine also from GitHub?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I commit all deleted files in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402776/how-do-i-commit-all-deleted-files-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a commit that deletes the files to your local repository and the push that commit to Github. To do that, do

1. `git commit -a` to commit all changes to tracked files, including deletions
2. `git push` to push the changes to Github