# How do you delete files that are already uploaded into a repository?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am unfamiliar with Git commands. How do I delete files that are already on a Bitbucket repository? I want to delete some files so the next time when someone pulls, we can work on a project without having those extra files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your commiting your code use `$ git add -u` to add the files you deleted while working on the repo just like you would use `git add .` to add new files and changes

Covered a bit more in this question/answer [How do I commit all deleted files in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402776/how-do-i-commit-all-deleted-files-in-git)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a commit that removes this file:

```
git rm /path/to/file
git commit
```

And then just push it as you would with any other commit.