# How to add and commit removals made with "rm" instead of "git rm"?

Tags: git, version-control

I deleted a bunch of files and directories from a Git repository using `rm`, the Finder, etc.

I'm looking for a Git command that'll record these to the index as marked for removal, as if I had called `git rm` on them.

I understand `git add -u` will do this, along with a bunch of other things. I'd like my command to exclusively handle removals.

Comment: Related, but not an exact duplicate: [Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/492558/456814). The other question already states that `git rm` can stage the removed files, it's just looking for a way to stage them all with a single invocation of `git rm`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Without spaces in filenames:

```
$ git rm `git ls-files -d`
```

More robust:

```
$ git ls-files -z -d | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty git rm
```

Comment: Note that it needs to be run from your repo's top-level directory.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look what Jonio C Hamano wrote in "[Re: [PATCH 1/2] Documentation: 'git add -A' can remove files](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/134696)" post at git mailing list, namely that this question looks like [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) (you are asking about assumed solution Y to the problem, instead about the problem X itself).  The solution to problem (if it is really "XY problem" situation) might be:

- **`git commit -a`**, which would automatically pick up deletions, committing current state of tracked files in working directory
- **`git add -A`**, which would add not ignored untracked files and remove no longer existing files, e.g. if you want to create commit from sideways update of working directory, e.g. unpacking a snapshot or result of rsync.

Nevertheless if what you ask is a problem (and not solution), then as you can see from other answers there are tools in place to do it.

Comment: This answers the question directly: git commit -a

Answer (score 4):

Charles Bailey's answer nudged me towards this, but I still welcome something shorter.

```
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D | xargs git rm
```

Answer (score 2):

In Git 2.0, `git add` behaves like `git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>` which ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

You can use `git add --all <pathspec>` to record the removals.

Run `git status` to check the paths you removed from your working tree.

Answer (score 0):

This command will give you a list of all deleted files which will be forward to git rm. So all files will be removed. If no deleted files were found, nothing will be happen:

`git ls-files -z -d | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty git rm`