# Remove tracked ignorned files from repo but not locally

Tags: git, gitignore

I keep running into a scenario where someone on our team pushes an initial commit without first adding a .gitignore to their project.  This results in a bunch of files ending up in the repo that we don't want tracked.

`git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`
gives me a list of files that are ignored by .gitignore

and

`git rm --cached <file>`
lets me remove files one at a time from the repo, but keeps them in my working directory (which I want)

Is there a way I can pipe the file list from `ls-files` to `rm --cached`  (or some other method altogether that will allow me to remove the tracked, ignored files from my repo)?

One of our team members wrote a shell script that uses regex to do it, but I'm looking for a command-line only solution (if one exists).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
git rm --cached $(git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore)
```

(Following the same idea than what works for deleted files in 
"[git remove files which have been deleted](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1246/git-remove-files-which-have-been-deleted)", or in "[git: how to add/commit removals made via vanilla rm?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856694/6309)", or "[Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147119/6309)").

Or: a simple pipe could work too:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

Comment: The first line works for me. The pipe solution gives me a fatal error: `fatal: pathspec 'path/to/file1 path/to/file2' did not match any files`

Comment: The second command probably failed for you because the first command succeeded; those files are no longer in the repository, so the error was being raised on trying to remove files no longer there.