# Deleting Files using Git/GitHub

Tags: git, github

First off, I'm new to Git.

I deleted a bunch of files locally on my Mac using Finder. I want the files that I deleted to no longer show in the current branch, but they do.

Any Git users know a command to update the index?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk

Answer (score 225, accepted):

I think this would be a simpler way to do what you want:

```
git add . -A
```

Then you would just do:

```
git commit -m "removed some files"
```

As noted above.

Comment: Thank you. And I had just written alias in `bash` to do the above. 

Amazing.

Comment: If you added a file in the same "stage" git will assume a rename. Anything to do about that or should you commit those separately?

Comment: @KimPrince - According to [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html), "-A
--all
Like -u, but match <filepattern> against files in the working tree in addition to the index. That means that it will find new files as well as staging modified content and removing files that are no longer in the working tree."

Comment: @KimPrince `git help add` will tell you what `-A` means and lists all other switches as well.

Comment: This does a lot more than just removing deleted files. It adds all files that are changed in the directory so this is not really a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 19):

You can see deleted files, which are still 'tracked' with:

```
git ls-files --deleted
```

To delete files from a branch, you can do something like this:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

From `man git-rm`:

> Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index. git-rm will not remove a file from just your working directory. (There is no option to remove a file
>        13        only from the work tree and yet keep it in the index; use /bin/rm if you want to do that.)

Finally, to commit the "removal" do something like:

```
git commit -m "removed some files"
```

Comment: Then you need to commit the change - `git commit -m "removed some files"`

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if this has been added to git since the previous answers, but I just used

```
git add -u
git commit -m "Removed some files"
```

to achieve the same thing.

Comment: This works for the listed use case, but this does not just add the deletion of the files. It adds all of the files that have been changed in any way, so this is not generally a good way to remove all deleted files unless that's the only changes you've made.

Answer (score 2):

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch deletefile.name' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git commit -m "Removed deletefile.name"
git push origin master --force
```

Replace deletefile.name with the file to remove. For in-depth detailed explanation go through the nice article https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data