# Files doesn't get deleted on github, while they are deleted on development machine?

Tags: git, file, github

I have deleted a set of files from my local development machine, however they are not deleted on GitHub and are thus showing on my production machine again when I deploy.

How can I force these files to be deleted in the next commit?

Comment: do you use " git add . " before commit?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to use **git add -u**

It'll remove files that has been manually deleted from your git files.
Just `commit` and `push`normally after that.

Check out the [git cheat sheets](http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/) for others git commands.

And also check that thread:  [git rm multiple files that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/git-rm-multiple-files-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
   git rm file
or 
   git rm -f file
if you have already delete the file
you have to commit after that

see : http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html for more detail on git rm