# RSS feed for updates to Git

Tags: git, rss, updates

Is there an RSS/Atom feed or a mailing list for updates to Git that I can subscribe to? I find it hard to keep up-to-date with the latest version, as I have no way on knowing when a new version is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For msysgit (windows port), it's simply the feed provided by Google Code:

http://code.google.com/feeds/p/msysgit/downloads/basic

But since there's a central location for git related stuff (http://git-scm.com), the better thing would be to have the feeds provided from there. Maybe you could write them a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

http://git-blame.blogspot.de/atom.xml

You might want to check following additional sources:

http://git-blame.blogspot.de/

https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=jfgbl2mrlipp4pb6ieih0qr3so%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Los_Angeles

Comment: That's a great way to find out about Git development and new versions that are released, but doesn't let me know when a new version is available for my platform. Still, it is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Git mailing list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git) which you can join to stay up to date.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a list/feed that pretty much just contains new release notification

Answer (score 0):

It was not easy, but I found it. On the official page https://git-scm.com/community you can find link to users list archive. There you can use "search" and "Atom feed" link to have atom feed with announcements: https://public-inbox.org/git/?q=ANNOUNCE&x=A