# Is git stash branch-specific or for the whole repository?

Tags: git, git-stash

I went into a branch and did some work.  I wanted to go into another branch but didn't want to commit so I did `git stash`.  Then I did `git checkout <otherbranch>`.  I did some work there and, just like in the first branch, I wanted to switch out of it before committing the work.  So I did `git stash` there too.  I switched back to the first branch and tried to unstash it (`git stash pop`) thinking it would get the stash from that specific branch.  I was surprised that it unstashed the stash from `<otherbranch>` (latest stashed).  I was under the impression that stash is branch-specific but this behavior indicates that there is only one stash for the whole local repository.

Is `git stash` branch-specific or for the whole repository?  If it is for the whole repository, can I pass options to it to make it branch-specific?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To see the current stash stack:

```
git stash list
```

To pick a specific stash from the stack, refer to it by the `stash@{number}` shown by the above.

If you want the behavior to be per-branch, you can just make a commit (or multiple commits) on the branch.  You can always "unmake" the commit(s) later (e.g., with `git reset`, either `--soft` or `--mixed`; see the [git reset documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html); or with `git rebase -i` to keep only the eventual "real" commit(s) while discarding the temporaries).

(To really emulate `git stash` you need at least two commits, one for the index state and one for the work-tree state.  If you're not planning to save and restore the index state, though, you can just `git add -A` the entire work-tree state and put that in the temporary commit.  Alternatively, `git stash` is a shell script so you could copy and modify it pretty easily to make it work per-branch by default, using, e.g., `refs/pb-stash/branch` as its working name-space, rather than the single global `refs/stash` for the entire repo.  You'd still be able to bring a stash from one branch to another by naming it explicitly.)

Comment: do you know how to display the file list of each `stash list` item in addition to just a description?

Comment: `git stash show` (or `git stash show stash@{<number>}` for something other than the `@{0}` version) gives you a `diff --stat`; add `-p` to get a larger diff.  Note: this compares the "work tree" in the ["stash bag"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20412685/1256452) against the commit it hangs from; there's no front-end interface to see what's in the "index" in the given stash-bag.

Comment: worth mentioning that `git-stash list` takes options of `git-log`, so you can things like `git stash list --grep$(git branch --current-branch)` to get stash entries that were made on a branch with the same name as the current one

Comment: My comment should say `git stash list --grep=$(git branch --show-current)`

Answer (score 83):

No and No. git stash is per-repository.

[Here](https://www.devroom.io/2008/04/23/git-using-the-stash/) is a nice page on how to use it.

Comment: does the second stash overwrite the first ?  IOW, if i do two stashes but no unstash in between, do I lose the first stash?

Comment: Nope the you get a stack (last-in-first-out) of stashes. You push a stash to your stash-stack, then another then you pop out the 2nd then you pop out the first, etc.

Comment: "No and No" is a confusing answer since the OP's first question is an either/or.

Comment: The "No and No" doesn't bring any elements or clarity to the answer, it's even confusing. But the page you link to provides a nice explanation.

Answer (score 47):

I am not sure why every answer here suggest to emulate stash with `commit`+`reset`. Stash is perfectly fine to use.

**So here is the stash workflow:**

Whenever you have to switch the branch and your not ready to commit, save your changes to the stack

```
git stash save "Your custom stash message"
```

(if you dont want a custom message, simply use `git stash`).

When you return to a branch, you can see the stash list like this:

```
git stash list
```

[image]

If you on branch `FixIssue0203` you could use use `git stash pop` because this will apply the top `stash@{0}` and remove it from stash.

However, if your in branch `ImproveReadme` you should first apply the stash 1 `git stash apply stash@{1}` and then remove stash 1 from stack `git stash drop stash@{1}`.

That's it!

If you want to only stash individual files, things are a bit tricky. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305243/2311074 for more. If you happen to use jetbrains, they have a feature called shelve so that you can cherry pick files that you may want to reuse later: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html (It's not part of GIT)

Comment: you saved my life, I stashed on multiple branches and when I git stash pop, I saw a conflict which wasn't what I wanted to pop. I thought it got over written and I lost my old stash. but ```git stash list``` and ```git stash apply stash@{1}``` let me pick out my old stash. which saves me many hours. thanks!

Answer (score 28):

`git stash` is not per-branch.

- Instead of `git stash` (which can be lost easily when you have lots of stashes and branches)
- **I suggest doing a `git commit` to save the unfinished code in your branch and when you are ready to finish the code do a `git reset ${COMMIT_HASH_VALUE}` to get the unfinished code back**
- **`git commit` and `git reset` when used *together* correctly can simulate a `git stash` for a specific branch**

Here is a common real-life scenario that demonstrates the value and the usage the `commit` and `reset` commands:

- you are working on feature branch X and your code doesn't even compile or pass the tests
- there is a bug that is higher priority than the current new feature and so you must start work immediately on the bug fix
- rather than do a git stash (and the stash gets lost in the mix because you have many stashes and many branches)
- you can do a `git commit` on feature branch X

  - write down the `COMMIT_HASH_VALUE` for later
- checkout a new branch Y for the hot fix
- finish the hot fix on branch Y (do a merge request to get the hot fix into the baseline and delete the hot fix branch)
- then checkout the feature branch X again
- **to pop your unfinished work that didn't compile or pass testing --> just do a `git reset ${COMMIT_HASH_VALUE}`**

(FYI the default for `git reset` is `--mixed`)

Comment: A handy shortcut for resetting in this scenario is `git reset HEAD~1`.

Comment: @samHH i have had one too many instances with git reset HEAD^1 accidently being hit twice... so i choose to not use `HEAD^1` or `HEAD~1`.

Comment: Why does stash tell you "On BranchName" if it is not branch-specific? Just to help you keep track of where it came from?

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question but I believe it answers the use case you are referring to eg what Trevor Boyd Smith alluded to in the accepted answer.

"Here is a common real-life scenario that demonstrates the value and the usage the commit and reset commands:

you are working on feature branch X and your code doesn't even compile or pass the tests
there is a bug that is higher priority than the current new feature and so you must start work immediately on the bug fix
rather than do a git stash **(and the stash gets lost in the mix because you have many stashes and many branches)"** Bolded this because this happens to LOTS of people.

What I do is have literally 5 copies of the same repository and name the root folder appropriately so you can switch to a working branch in literally seconds without losing track of where you are. You can even open a second instance of your IDE so if you a multi tasker you can work on your 20 minute hotfix in folder2 and go back to your larger task in folder 1 when you are done.

It requires some house keeping of which folder is used for what, they should all be regularly kept up to date. I also recommend that root of these working directories be backed up/sync'd regularly to some kind of versioned file storage so you can always get yourself out of any mess you get into. Git purists may disagree with this workflow, however it works for myself and I've seen many other developers use this workflow.

Pros and cons. Personally I find this the fastest way to do the use case mentioned by trevor without worrying about a stash getting lost or which branch the stash should be re-applied to. Means you can merge/diff files from your uncommitted/unstashed/completely broken mess in your current branch that you don't ever want committed by accident as well.

Comment: This seems like "Why am I using VCS"

Comment: I'm not following. There are plenty of reasons to use VCS. Sometimes you want to check out something else without interrupting the flow of what you are doing. There is a real switching cost associated with stashing/checking out etc etc. This saves time and improves productivity.