# PhpStorm and shelving untracked files

Tags: git, phpstorm

Is it possible in PhpStorm 2018.2 to shelve untracked/new files?

It doesn't seem to be but I can't find a definitive answer on this and [this support question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000104650-Remove-new-files-when-shelving-changes) seems to suggest it was at least possible in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (despite this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008816/8020009)
Shelving/stashing untracked files isn't implemented yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-62354 - feel free to vote/comment for it in order to increase its priority and get notified about updates.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The jetbrains issue you linked to is about git stash, not shelving. Do you know of a "shelve improvements" issue I can vote on?

Comment: `git shelve` doesn't exist in Git. Once above-mentioned issue would get addressed, shelving would also work the way you want it.

Comment: I know `git shelve` doesn't exist. I am only referring to PhpStorm's internal shelve feature. Nothing to do with git. In any case, you answered what I wanted to know. Thanks!