# What is the difference Git Stash and Idea Shelve?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-stash, shelve

I know that shelve is not a Git command and both of them is used to put aside unfinished work. What is the differences? Which one is more flexible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Shelve vs Stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008139/git-shelve-vs-stash)

Answer (score 3):

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-on-several-features-simultaneously.html

Shelve is easier to use in the IDE - it is better integrated with the UI. It also works independently of the VCS in use.

Stash is git specific. From a feature perspective, stash on the command line is likely more powerful, but not all stash features are supported in IntelliJ UI, so in the IDE stash and shelve are likely even. If you do not use other git clients, Shelve should work fine for you.