# Git PathSpec Issue on Git Stash

Tags: git, git-stash

When I run the new version *2.13.0.windows.1* of its new command `stash -p -- {pathspec}` as

`git stash -p -- AB.Dir1/Dir2/DestinationHierarchyCreator.cs`

it reports the error

> error: pathspec 'AB.Dir1/Dir2/DestinationHierarchyCreator.cs' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Yet when I do a `git status`, *where I copied the file from actually*, it reports

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/project/develop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:  AB.Dir1/Dir2/DestinationHierarchyCreator.cs
```

If I go to the directory the files lives in and do `git stash -p -- DestinationHierarchyCreator.cs` It fails with the same error.

If I run the command `git stash -p -- *.cs` then I can save fragments to the stash.

---

So is my understanding of the `git stash -p` option wrong, or is my handling of the pathspec incorrect for individual file(s) or something else?

Comment: Strange. I don't see any issue yet on https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=stash%20is%3Aissue%20 or http://marc.info/?l=git&w=4&r=1&s=stash+match&q=b

Comment: @VonC I am thinking this one is user error first, before finding fault with git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem. It appears that `git stash` pathspecs must be relative to the repository root (top) -- not to your current working dir.

Since `git status` ("unlike many other Git commands") shows paths "[relative to the current directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_output) if you are working in a subdirectory," this seems prone to confusion.

So if your current working directory is, say, ~/dev/git_project_root/subdir, you'd need to use:

```
git stash -p -- subdir/AB.Dir1/Dir2/DestinationHierarchyCreator.cs
```

(The wildcard `git stash -p -- *.cs` worked because it was matching all modified *.cs files below your root -- and probably you only had that one.)

Comment: Just chiming in to say that I just encountered this (on Linux). Do you know whether this is a known issue or if it is an intentional 'feature'?

Comment: I'm guessing it's either intentional or an oversight. But that's not entirely clear. The [`pathspec` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefpathspecapathspec) say, "See the documentation of each command for whether paths are relative to the current directory or toplevel." But the [`git stash push` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-push-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--ltpathspecgt82308203) don't say how that command treats pathspecs.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on Windows: it works on a normal folder without '`.`'

```
C:\Users\vonc\data\git\git>git st
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Documentation/blame-options.txt

C:\Users\vonc\data\git\git>git stash -- Documentation\blame-options.txt
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b14f27f91 Tenth batch for 2.13
```

Even in a bash session, and with the -p, it does still work

```
vonc@bvonc MINGW64 ~/data/git/git (master)
$ git stash -p -- Documentation/blame-options.txt
diff --git a/Documentation/blame-options.txt b/Documentation/blame-options.txt
index dc41957af..96a5b1b4a 100644
--- a/Documentation/blame-options.txt
+++ b/Documentation/blame-options.txt
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 -b::
        Show blank SHA-1 for boundary commits.  This can also
        be controlled via the `blame.blankboundary` config option.
-
+sss
 --root::
        Do not treat root commits as boundaries.  This can also be
        controlled via the `blame.showRoot` config option.
Stash this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? y

Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: b14f27f91 Tenth batch for 2.13
```

---

On a folder with '`.`':

```
vonc@bvonc MINGW64 ~/data/git/git (master)
$ git stash -p -- a.b/c
error: pathspec 'a.b/c' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?
```

So that could be a possible issue.

---

Note, With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), no more "`Show blank SHA-1 for boundary commits`": A few end-user facing messages have been updated to be hash-algorithm agnostic.

See [commit 4279000](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4279000d3e11a374a0a28d8284ca2774bd842c75) (13 Aug 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2a978f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a978f827388a4645a405a2ea9c203a7940f0281), 19 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`messages`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4279000d3e11a374a0a28d8284ca2774bd842c75): avoid SHA-1 in end-user facing messages

> There are still a handful mentions of SHA-1 when we meant the (hexadecimal) object names in end-user facing messages.
> Rewrite them.
>
> I was hoping that this can mostly be s/SHA-1/object name/, but a few messages needed rephrasing to keep the result readable.

Then new error message will be:

```
Do not show object names of boundary commits
```

Comment: For me, the subfolders have a `.` in the name, and then there is a child folder. `AB.Dir1/Dir2/`. I will attempt to do it on a sub folder.

Comment: @OmegaMan I agree. I edited the answer to illustrate how a folder with a `.` in it could be problematic.

Comment: Something else is going on. I attempted to stash from a lower directory without the `.` issue and still receive the same error. I will continue to investigate.