# git add -A :/ on Git 2.X and relationship with pathspec

Tags: git

I have read in [several places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146646/what-is-the-difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add-update-for-github) that the behavior of `git add -A` [has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146646/what-is-the-difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add-update-for-github) a bit over time.

As of 2.x (e.g. Git 2.5.0), what does `git add -A :/` exactly do? I couldn't find the option `:` or `:/` in [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add). Is it a `pathspec`? How so? The examples the documentation provides only show glob patterns (e.g. `*.c`) or simple path specifications (e.g. `dir` to add anything under `dir`).

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary.html   search for pathspec:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since git 2.0, `git add -A` and `git add -A :/` are the same.
But the magic pathspec `:/` is not new and dates back from git 1.7.6 (Apr 2011). See [commit 8a42c98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a42c9850177cc91e9f38779e8aca89682a02975). It is documented in [`Documentation/glossary-content.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2635c2b8bfc9aec07b7f023d8e3b3d02df715344/Documentation/glossary-content.txt#L327-L340)

> A pathspec that begins with a colon `:` has special meaning.
>   In the short form, the leading colon `:` is followed by zero or more "magic
>   signature" letters (which optionally is terminated by another colon `:`),
>   and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path.

```
:top: or :/
```

> The magic word `top` (magic signature: `/`) makes the pattern match from the root of the working tree, even when you are  running the command from inside a sub-directory.

---

Note that if you want to add a folder named '`:/`' (`git add -A :/`), this will be possible only in git 2.7 (Nov 2015)
See [commit 29abb33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29abb33978f713cd0a5cc3687bf61077b0928840) (25 Oct 2015) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).

> Since Git 2.0, "`add -u`" and "`add -A`" run from a subdirectory without any pathspec mean "everything in the working tree" (before 2.0, they were limited to the current directory).
>   The limiting to the current directory was implemented by inserting "`.`" to the command line when the end user did not give us any pathspec.
>   At 2.0, we updated the code to insert "`:/`" (instead of '`.`') to consider everything from the top-level, by using a pathspec magic "`top`".

(This is no longer needed, and fixed in said commit 29abb33: the implementation of `git add -A` no longer use `:/` for the upcoming git 2.7)

> Incidentally such a simplification also fixes a corner case bug that
>   stems from the fact that "`:/`" does not necessarily mean any magic.
>   A user would say "`git --literal-pathspecs add -u :/`" from the command line when she has a directory '`:`' and wants to add everything in it (and she knows that her `:/` will be taken as 'everything under the sun' magic pathspec unless she disables the magic with `--literal-pathspecs`).
>
> The internal use of '`:/`' would behave the same way as such an explicitly given ":/" when run with "--literal-pathspecs", and will not add everything under the sun as the code originally intended.

Since that internal use of `:/` is no more, a `git --literal-pathspecs add -u :/` will actually work, and add files under the folder named "column" ('`:`').

Comment: Thank you VonC, when you said above `"(This is no longer needed, and fixed in that commit)"` what exactly did you refer to? What comes right after?

Comment: @Josh I am referring to https://github.com/git/git/commit/29abb33978f713cd0a5cc3687bf61077b0928840: its implementation (of `git add -A`) no longer use `:/` for the upcoming git 2.7, which allows `git add -A :/` to actually be able to add a folder named `:/` (instead of being overridden by the magic path `:/` used internally for `git add -A` before that commit)

Answer (score 5):

`git add -A :/` will add all changes to index even if you are currently not in the top level project folder. But in later git versions, it's the same as `git add -A`

Say you have your project like this:

```
➜  top git:(master) tree .
.
├── b.c
└── subfolder
    └── a.c
```

Then you changed code in `b.c`, but you are currently in `subfolder`

```
➜  subfolder git:(master) ✗ git st
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../b.c

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Running `git add .` now will **NOT** add `b.c` to your index, and old `git add -A` will **NOT** too. But in older git, `git add -A :/` will do the trick.

> If no pathspec is given when -A option is used, all files in the
>              entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit
>              the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

For more information, please read
`git help add`
`git help gitglossary`