# Git equivalent for GitHub Desktop's "Discard all changes" (not git stash though)

Tags: git, github-desktop

GitHub Desktop has a nice feature named "Discard All Changes"

How do I do the same thing using **Git CLI**, but **NOT** use `git stash`?

[image]

Comment: As in, "get rid of all my changes since the last commit"?

Answer (score 0):

Using:

- the more recent [`git restore` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)
- the [magic pathspec `:/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33449169/6309)

That would be, from anywhere inside your repository:

```
git restore -SW :\
```

That would restore your working tree and index to HEAD content