# What does git add --update do?

Tags: git

What happens to the state of a file after it has `git add -u` applied to it?

I had package.json under **Changes not staged for commit**.  I did a `git add -u package.json` and basically the file disappeared from showing up in `git status`. What is the status of my package.json? What happened to the changes made to this file earlier?

This is my screen output, before:

[image]

and after:

[image: AFTER: git status doesn't show package.json]

(I wonder if the `git add --refresh` did any damage.)

**Dear all**: I am not asking for the difference between -A and -u. I would like to know what happened to the changes that were earlier made to the file after -u is applied.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146646/what-is-the-difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add-update-for-github?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Aeseir I had studied that earlier, but couldn't understand what it meant by removed from the working tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between git add -A and git add --update :/ for github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146646/what-is-the-difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add-update-for-github)

Comment: @OldGeezer have a look at this page for explanation on working trees, it is the basis of GIT structures. It will help you out as it did me. https://backlog.com/git-tutorial/intro/intro1_4.html

Comment: @ObsidianAge I had read that earlier. What does "removed from the entire working tree" mean? What happened to the changes in the file? Do you mean same as `checkout` has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but couldn't understand what it meant by removed from the working tree.

Since git add -u records only *modifications* to the existing index, that includes *deletion* as well.
That is what update or remove previously tracked files from the entire working tree.

In your case, the file is not removed, but adding it make it somehow identical to HEAD (the current checked out commit), which means it is not listed as being committed.

That can be possible for instance if you have a:

- clean content driver (which restore its content to what it was originally in HEAD when checked out)
- or a `core.eol` .gitattributes directive (which restore the eol to what it was in HEAD)

Comment: Thanks. I see. I think the file was unchanged other than EOL differences.