# gitpython not adding, pushing or committing, and no error message

Tags: gitpython

I'm trying to add, push and commit using gitpython, to push everything in "C:\users\Blah Blah Blah.git" to my bitbucket acct.

Below is my code:

```
from git import Repo,remote
PATH_OF_GIT_REPO = r'C:\\users\\Blah Blah Blah' 
COMMIT_MESSAGE = 'comment from python script'

repo = Repo(PATH_OF_GIT_REPO)
repo.git.add(update=True)
repo.index.commit(COMMIT_MESSAGE)
origin = repo.remote(name='origin')
origin.push()
```

Nothing seems to be happening, and I don't get any error messages neither. 
I'd appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: What did you expect to be committed? Maybe there are no changes?

Comment: Oh, well I was expecting to have everything in my repo path added. Doesn't add(update=True) look for chages? I added a new file to the folder and I want it to be added to my bitbucket. So, there definitely are changes, because I don't see the file added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between “git add -A” and “git add --update :/”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146646/what-is-the-difference-between-git-add-a-and-git-add-update). I suppose `repo.git.add(update=True)` is equivalent to `git add --update`, which does not add untracked files.