# Git: How to commit a manually deleted file?

Tags: git, github

In my git repository I manually deleted a file(`rm`) after moving it to another folder. I than committed all the changes to my repo but now when I do `git status .`

```
ronnie@ronnie:/home/github/Vimfiles/Vim$ git status .
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    plugin/dwm.vim
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now, how should I commit so that `dwm.vim` is deleted from the plugin folder in my remote repo. I know that I have to use `git add && git commit` but I have no file to commit/add because `/plugin/dwm.vim` is already deleted.

Comment: You can use git add -u

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk), I think.

It's better if you do `git rm <fileName>`, though.

Comment: Ya I know that I should use `git rm` but `rm` is in my habit so sometimes I just forgot about using `git rm`.

Comment: Ah, sure, happens to me as well from time to time :)

Comment: Answer is `git add -u`, `git commit -a`, or `git add -A`? -1 for confusion.

Comment: `git rm` can be used after the `rm` has already deleted the file.  It just updates the local repository.

Comment: git add <folder path with missing file>

Answer (score 103):

Use `git add -A`, this will include the deleted files.

Warning: this also adds all files in the directory that are not already in the repository.

Note: use `git rm`  for certain files.

Comment: If someone's just wanting to stage the deletion of a single file, I don't think it's a good idea to suggest `git add -A`, since that will also (a) stage all modifications to already tracked files and (b) stage untracked and unignored files.  You might want to update your answer with a warning about that.

Comment: on the other hand when you refactor an entire project and move/delete folders and files you can not get back to do that for just that reason each file/folder using git. git add -A should be event one command.

Comment: @MarkLongair now can you tell us about how can we undo this mistake :)

Answer (score 33):

It says right there in the output of `git status`:

```
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
```

so just do:

```
git rm <filename>
```

Comment: This is confusing, though: 'use "git add/rm' — which is it? What's the difference, in this scenario, between the two?

Comment: Why not try them and find out? I think you'll find the behavior quite sensible in both cases. ("Add a deleted file" and "remove a deleted file")