# What is the equivalent of git add - u for removing files?

Tags: git

While git add -u stage all modified tracked files, it doens't remove deleted files.

I tried "git rm -u" but it didn't work. What is the git command for removing deleted tracked files ?

EDIT: with git status I see the deleted files under "Changes not staged for commit:"

I could checkout them and do a git rm on each... but there may be a better solution.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/492558/1615903

Comment: I tried git ls-files --deleted from the answer above, but it doens't show these deleted files.

Comment: Well, it may be duplicated, but why "git ls-files --deleted" output nothing ?

Comment: Are you perhaps inside a subdirectory?

Comment: You are right, I thought git could work regardless of the current subdirectory. Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of git do you use ? I use version `1.7.9.5` and when I run `git add -u`, tracked files removed from the disk are staged for deletion.

Extra note : you don't need to run `git checkout <file>` before `git rm <file>`. You may need to use the `--` command line separator to clearly indicate that you meant a file name, and not a branch name :

```
git rm -- <file>
```

Comment: I too use git 1.7.9.5, you are right it should work with "git add -u" but maybe it didn't because I actually moved the files.

Answer (score 0):

You should always delete tracked files using [`git rm`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) - this will automatically stage the deletion, so that it's included in the next commit.

[`git add -A`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) will stage absolutely everything that is not ignored - including deleted files, new files, and modified files.

Edit: as it turned out, the problem was that you were inside a subdirectry in your repo, and the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147119/1615903) worked.

Comment: I agree that using "git rm" would be the easy way, but this time I forgot and deleted these files with rm.