# Git alias in nested command

Tags: git, alias

I know how to create simple aliases, but there is this very useful command to unstage deleted files from disk that I cannot make it work.

`git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)`

(from here [Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk))

I have tried with:

```
git config --global alias.cleandeleted 'rm $(git ls-files --deleted)'
```

But when I write:

```
git cleandeleted
```

I get the following error:

```
error: unknown option `deleted)'
usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `$(...)`. As you have defined it, git only handles git intern commands and doesn't know how to deal with `$(...)`.

There is a trick to make you command work:

```
git config --global alias.cleandeleted '!git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)'
```

Because of the `!` the alias works as if the command was given directly to the command line.