# Sync GitHub with file system as is

Tags: github

I've done some commits to my repository, but now I've deleted some files that I didn't need, but after other commits, they haven't been deleted in the repo.

For example:

In my initial commit I inserted files `main.py`, `class1.py` and `class2.py`

In my second commit I added the file `class3.py` and deleted `class1.py`, but that file is still in the repo.

Is there any way to just synchronize the entire repo with a command or something without having to delete files manually?

Comment: Did you commit the deletion of `class1.py`?

Comment: Do you commit deletions the same way as changes or is there a specific way? I do a `git add .` and then `git commit`

Comment: I did `git status` and the deleted files are still there, so I guess the deletions weren't commited. I'll look into how to achieve that. Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 0):

You would need `git add -A .` or at least `git add -u .`, to record addition *and* deletion.

See "[How do I commit all deleted files in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402793/6309)".

With Git 2.0, you can type anywhere your repo:

```
git add -u :/
```

That would record all deletion from the top of the repo.

See also "[Difference between “`git add -A`” and “`git add .`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162511/6309)" for the importance of the '`.`'.

Comment: That did the job. Thanks a lot, VonC.