# How to git rm all deleted files from repo, excluding others

Tags: git, git-add, git-rm

I have used this post [Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk) to figure out how to remove multiple files  with git rm at once.

Now, I'd like to do this, excluding one directory. I tried this:

```
git rm $(git ls-files --deleted --exclude='sites/all/modules/imagecache_actions/')
```

but it didn't work. Am I misusing the exclude tag?

Comment: If the only changes are deletions, just use `git add -u .` to stage all updates/deletions, then use `git reset <directory>` to unstage the one directory you want to leave alone.

Comment: Thats the issue, there are modifications too. So, I'd like a clean way of excluding them

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-files -d | sed '/^sites\/all\/modules\/imagecache_actions\//d' | xargs git rm
```

The `-x --exclude` option only works with untracked files.