# How to remove distant folders added to .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have added a folder (which was previously synchronized) to my .gitignore file.

Fine.
Now when I make a git add -A, git commit -m "ok", git push, I still see this folder in my distant rep.

I'd like that folder to be completely ignored and not appear in my distant rep. Can I remove it from those distant rep ?

Comment: please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to record the deletion of that folder in your repo first, and push that deletion to your distant repo:

(The `--cached` option of [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) allows you to remove an element from the Git index without deleting it from the working tree on the disk itself)

```
git rm --cached -r yourFolder
git commit -m "remove folder"
git push
```

*Then*:

- the `.gitignore` will ignore that folder
- the distant repo won't show the folder anymore.

Comment: nice, it's working well. note, i just had to skip the git add -A which would cancel the previous line effect

Comment: @SébastienVassaux right: `git rm` modifies the index directly, no `git add` necessary. I have removed it from the answer.