# Can't seem to be able to delete from the local GIT repository

Tags: git, github

I don't seem to be getting it. From [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk) I'm trying to correct a commit where I had added a build folder with large files.

I've deleted the folder from the local disk.
I've:

```
$ git add -u
$ git commit
```

But when I push, I get a too big file error, two `.pdb's` are still in the local git. But I can't see them any longer with a:

```
$ git status
```

I've done a:

```
$ git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
The `.pdb` file or `Debug` folder is not on the list.
```

I've tried every variation of what I can find on the web, no luck. The push in part:

```
$ git push origin master
```

or just

```
$ git push
```

and:

```
Counting objects: 499, done.
remote: warning: File project/Debug/CAD.pdb is 68.07 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File project/Debug/vc141.pdb is 66.48 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

Yet when:

```
$ git rm --cached -r ./project/Debug
fatal: pathspec './project/Debug' did not match any files
```

or even:

```
$ git rm --cached ./project/Debug/CAD.pdb
fatal: pathspec './project/Debug/CAD.pdb' did not match any files

$ git commit -m "deleted files"

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Yet it keeps showing up in the `git push`.

using git version 2.9.2.windows.1
Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git status` says you have 2 commits that aren't in `origin/master`. One of them must be adding the file and the other must be deleting it.

You can check by running `git log --stat origin/master..master`, which shows the commits that aren't on GitHub, and the filenames they change.

You can combine the two commits into one by running `git rebase -i origin/master` and changing the start of the second line from `pick` to `squash`, meaning squash the later commit into the earlier commit.

Then, try pushing again.

Comment: Two ps's I did google the `commits` thing but no one came close to what you wrote. Also, I've put a Visual Studio `.getignore` in my local root. Should that be there or in the `.git` folder? I don't want to find out the hard way. :)