# How can I delete committed items that haven't been pushed to git yet?

Tags: git, github

I tried to push files that were too big for the GitHub limit and couldn't push them. I removed them from the folder, but they're still there, waiting to be committed, and it's blocking other push attempts too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing multiple files from a Git repo that have already been deleted from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk)

Comment: This is a better link, but it has a LOT of answers, only some of which apply: https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/1256452

Comment: The first link's solution didn't work, I'll try again with the new one. If it changes anything, I had committed something after the large files.

Comment: In a way, yes, but when I tried it then it didn't work, although the commands are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to the fact that Git doesn't push *files*.  Git pushes *commits*.

Git doesn't really *store* files either: Git stores *commits*.  Commits themselves store files, but the key point is, you either have all of a commit, or none of it.  There's no way to pick and choose just a few files out of it.

When you added the big files and committed, you made commits that have those files.  Then you made additional, later commits that *don't* have those files.

So, keeping in mind that each commit stores a full and complete snapshot of *all* of your files—well, all of the files that are in that commit, which might be more or fewer files than some earlier commit—let's look at the *rest* of a commit.  Besides the snapshot, a commit stores some *metadata:* some information about the commit itself.  For instance, the commits you made have your name and email address in them, from your `user.name` and `user.email` settings.  When you ran `git commit`, Git made you enter a *log message*, to say *why* you made the commit; the log message for each commit is part of that commit's metadata.

Commits are numbered, but not sequentially (that would be too easy!).  They have big ugly hash IDs as their numbers.  Every commit gets a *unique* hash ID, reserved for that commit forever more, and in a way, reserved for that commit long before you made it, except that the actual hash ID depends on *all* the metadata, and one of the items *in* the metadata is the date-and-time-stamp of when you made it.  So until you actually chose a particular second of a particular minute of a particular hour of a particular day (etc), we wouldn't know what the hash ID *would* be.  Still, that hash ID, from now on, means *that* commit.  Your Git and any other Git can exchange commits, and know if they have each other's commits, by just comparing hash IDs.

The last key piece of metadata, though, is that every commit<sup>1</sup> stores its previous commit's hash ID as its *parent*.  So every commit remembers which commit comes before it.

This means commits form a sort of backwards-pointing chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands for some big ugly hash ID.  Commit `H` holds earlier commit `G`'s big ugly hash ID as its parent; we say that `H` *points to* `G`.  Commit `G` holds `F`'s hash ID, so `G` points to `F`, and so on.

Note: the hash IDs are exquisitely sensitive to every bit of data in the commit.  This means no part of *any* commit can ever change.  (That's *why* it's OK to trust in the hash ID.)

When you run `git push`, your Git calls up another Git.  Your Git says: *Hey, I'd like to give you my latest commit `H`.  Do you have it yet?*  They say: *No, send it over.*  Your Git says: "To have `H` you need `G`, do you have it yet?*  They say *no, send that one too*, and so on.  This repeats until we reach a point where they say: *Oh, yes, I have that one.*

That's *how* your Git knows what it needs to send, and sends it all: just the right set of commits.

But you've got commit `H`, which doesn't have the big files, and commit `G`, which *does*, and then maybe you and they both have commit `F`.  So your Git insists on sending *both* commits to them.  That's because you *can't* have a commit, in Git, unless you have all of its parents.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Some commits store two or more previous-commit hash IDs.  These are *merge commits*.  At least one commit in any non-empty repository stores *no* previous hash ID: the very first commit someone makes *can't* remember a parent, as there *is no previous commit*.  This kind of commit is called a *root commit*.

<sup>2</sup>There *are* some ways to avoid having all of the parents, but they don't apply to this case.

---

#### What you need to do

What you need to do, then, is construct some *new* commit(s).

Commit `H` is sort of OK on its own, except it *isn't* on its own: it is indelibly linked to commit `G`, and commit `G` *isn't* OK because it has some really big files in it, that you don't want to have.  Commit `F` is OK and they they already have `F` ... or maybe `F` is bad too, and it's `E` that's OK and they already have.  Whatever your situation is, you have to figure out which commits are good and which aren't.

So, what we need to do is find out which commit they have, and which commits we have that are good and which are bad, and re-copy our good ones while leaving out our bad ones.  There are a lot of ways to do this, but often the *best* one is to use `git rebase -i`:

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

Our name `origin/master` is our Git's way of remembering *their* Git's `master`.  This assumes your current branch name is `master`, i.e., that the picture we should draw really looks like this:

```
...--F   <-- origin/master
      \
       G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Here, commit `G` is the one with the big file(s), and commit `H` is the one that takes them away again.  We'd like to *copy* `G`-plus-`H` such that the big files are *gone*.  Since `H` simply *removes* the file, we can use `git rebase -i`'s *squash* command to combine `G` and `H` into one new commit, `I`, that does what `G`+`H` did, all in one:

```
pick <hash> subject line for commit G
pick <hash> subject line for commit H
```

becomes:

```
pick <hash> subject line for commit G
squash <hash> subject line for commit H
```

We write this out and `git rebase` goes and squashes the two and invokes our editor to let us write the new commit message.

When the whole thing is done, we end up with this:

```
       I   <-- master (HEAD)
      /
...--F   <-- origin/master
      \
       G--H   [abandoned]
```

That is, we kept existing commit `F` without touching it at all.  Then we had Git extract `G`, pile `H` on top of it (removing the big files), and commit the result as new commit `I`.  Our Git then took our name `master` *off* commit `H`, which was OK except that it linked to `G`.  It now has our name `master` set to point to commit `I`.

We can now run `git push origin master` successfully: our Git will call up their Git, and say *I'd like to offer you commit `I` if you don't have it*.  They'll say *OK, what about `I`'s parents?*  Our Git will say *`I`'s parent is `F`.*  They'll say *Oh I have that one!*  Our Git will send commit `I` and then ask them to set *their* `master` to point to commit `I`.

If all goes well this time, they'll now have commit `I`.  They never see our `G` and `H` again, and neither do we: we no longer have a *name* by which to find the big ugly hash ID of commit `H`.

Eventually—after 30 or more days, typically, though you can tweak this—our Git notices that no one seems to *want* `H` at all, and that `G` can only be found by starting at `H` and working backwards.  So our Git will actually throw out commits `H` and `G` at this point (when the maintenance `git gc` command gets around to it, really), and our repository will shrink because we don't have the commit with the big file.

(If your commits are more complicated, you may need a somewhat fancier `git rebase`, or `git rebase -i` might no longer be the best tool for all of this.  A great deal depends on *exactly* what's wrong and whether there's more than one way to fix it.)

Comment: I have three commits. One is the big file, the second is the removal of those files, and the third is the addition of new files. When I put in the rebash command I saw:
```pick [commit1] [commit]
pick [commit2] [commit]
pick [commit3] [commit]```

I turned the 2nd pick line into squash. The bash is not prompting me to do anything else. How can I confirm the new choice?

Comment: That's the right sequence (pick + squash + pick). If you write out the file and let rebase continue, it should open the editor on the combined commit's message. Fix that up and write it out and exit the editor and rebase will then pick the third commit atop the combined commit. Note, however, if the combination of the add and then delete winds up being "do nothing", Git won't know how to continue: you'll get a message to the effect that the combined changes don't do anything and what should rebase do now? In this case the easiest thing is to start over and just drop two of the 3 commits.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, since nothing happened after I changed the pick to squash. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git rm {file1} {file2} ... {fileN}`? You have to tell git to remove the files from the source tree even if you delete the files themselves.

Comment: Do I have to put in the entire file path itself or can I just do something like ```git rm a.xyz```?

Comment: If you're in that directory, `cd my_directory`, you can just say `git rm my_file`.

Comment: It says that there is no such file or directory, yet when I try to push again I still get the errors as if they were still there.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492558/removing-multiple-files-from-a-git-repo-that-have-already-been-deleted-from-disk).